# Read Each Line of 2 Multiline Text Box

Tags: c#

Is there a way to read each line of 2 multi-line text box? In `textBox1` I have as a multi-line String containing a list of compressed files using the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo getExpandDLL = new DirectoryInfo(showExpandPath);
FileInfo[] expandDLL = getExpandDLL.GetFiles("*.dl_");
foreach (FileInfo listExpandDLL in expandDLL)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(listExpandDLL + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

At the moment part of my code is this:

```
textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace("dl_", "dll");
string cmdLine = textDir.Text + "\\" + textBox1.Text + " " + textDir.Text + "\\" + textBox2.Text;
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "expand.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Arguments = cmdLine.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The code above takes the name of the compressed file in textBox1 and renames it in textBox2 then runs expand.exe to expand the compressed file. The code basically gives expand.exe the following command as an example:

```
c:\users\nigel\desktop\file.dl_ c:\users\nigel\desktop\file.dll
```

it works great if the folder contains only one line of text in textBox1. With multi-lines of text the command is basically:

```
c:\users\nigel\desktop\loadsoffiles.dl_ etc and doesnt work!
```

Is there a way to read each line of textBox1, change the string and put it into textBox2 then pass the command to expand.exe?

```
string cmdLine = textDir.Text + "\\" + lineOFtextBox1 + " " + textDir.Text + "\\" + lineOftextBox2;
```

EDIT: Just to be clear: TextBox1 contains:

- somefile.dl_
- someMore.dl_
- evenmore.dl_

as a mulitline. My code takes that multiline text and puts it in textBox2 so it contains:

- somefile.dll
- someMore.dll
- evenmore.dll

is there a way to read each line /get each line of textBox1 and textBox2 and do 'stuff' with it?

thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure exactly what your problem is but if it's simply parsing multiple lines of text based on a newline character, then you should be able to do a `Regex.Split` very nicely on this.

Comment: Why do you put all output of `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` to textbox and then try to parse the string in it?

Comment: @ I4V its so textBox1 shows as a list the name of compressed files and its extension in dl_

Comment: What l4V is saying is that your textbox should be used for display only and you shouldn't parse it. You already have the data parsed so keep that safe and use it when you need it.

Comment: Right I understand you now. But the way expand.exe works is that I need path to the compressed file i.e .dl_ then the path and name of the expanded file so: c:\users\nigel\desktop\file.dl_ c:\users\nigel\desktop\file.dll. Hence why I try and Parse textBox1! But perhaps I should parse the Directory.GetFiles data... hmm thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need to do is loop over an array of strings, instead of working with a single string. Note that TextBox has a "Lines" property to give you the lines already split into an array

```
foreach(string line in textBox1.Lines)
{
    //your code, but working with 'line' - one at a time

}
```

So i think the your full solution would be:

```
foreach (string line in textBox1.Lines)
{
    string cmdLine = textDir.Text + "\\" + line + " " + textDir.Text + "\\" + line.Replace("dl_", "dll");
    var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "expand.exe",
                    Arguments = cmdLine.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty),
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    UseShellExecute = true
                }
        };
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Note that we're launching one process for every line in your textbox, which I think is the correct behaviour

Comment: thank you I have played with that already. The problem is the way my code works at the moment is that I rename each line of textBox1. So first Line get renamed form somefile.dl_ to somefile.dll in textBox2. Is there a way to rename 'line'? thank you.

Comment: absolutely fantastic. Thank you so much Rob. I can see the logic behind the code. But with such little experience I did not think of it myself. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First Google hit tells us the following:

```
string txt = TextBox1.Text;
string[] lst = txt.Split(new Char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Hi Grumble85, thank you for the reply. I dont think Split would help As textbox 1 is already a multi line text with one line on each.

Comment: That's garbage. Use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @banging Yep i've been using         Envionrment.Newline

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code

```
string a = txtMulti.Text;

string[] delimiter = {Environment.NewLine};

string[] b = a.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None);
```